# Spring WS with webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive returns Received error for request, Service Unavailable : Not Found [404]

Tags: jaxb, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I'm trying to ammend an existing SOAP Webservice that uses Spring-WS and JAXB on Tomcat. I've created the new WAR file with my changes and deployed it in the webapps foder under Tomcat installation.

When calling the original (already existing) methods of the service, the service SOAP request and response is fine. But when calling the service on the new method, I get  service SOAP response of service unavailable and not found [404]

```
2011-07-25 12:58:23,365 DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] - Opening [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnection@12b9f14] to [http://<service URL>]
2011-07-25 12:58:23,521 DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils] - SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Envelope1_1Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
2011-07-25 12:58:23,552 DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.support.SaajUtils] - SOAPElement [com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Body1_1Impl] implements SAAJ 1.3
2011-07-25 12:58:23,896 DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent] - Sent request [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:DelRequest xmlns:ns2="http://<changed_address>"><ns2:userId>ncc1@%</ns2:userId><ns2:dateFromMillis>1308956400000</ns2:dateFromMillis><ns2:dateToMillis>1311634800000</ns2:dateToMillis></ns2:DelRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>]
2011-07-25 12:58:25,318 DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] - Received error for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://<changed_address>}DelRequest]
```

2011-07-25 12:58:25,318 ERROR [net.msgplugin.controller.DeleteController] - Conversation service unavailable at: http://, Not Found [404] , null

I've imported the project into Eclipse and have made the following changes to the project properties:

1) With in Project Facets, I've checked the 'Dynamic Web Module' and 'Java' Facets.
2) In Java EE Module Dependencies, I've checked Maven Dependencies.

Two things which are to be noted here are:

a) The developer was using JBoss when developing the Webservice but recently the project was chagned to Tomcat.
b) The project has a MAVEN folder structure, hence the web.xml file is in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF folder rather than WebContent/WEB-INF, taht got created when I selected the 'Dynamic Web Module' facet.

Any suggestions wld be hugely appreciated?

Thanks

========================================================================

HI

I managed to fix the Not Found [404] error but am now getting another error. 
Upon further investigation and debuggin into WebServiceTemplate and MessageDispatcher classes, I found that following output on the console:

```
DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter] - Accepting incoming [org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpServletConnection@11f05a1] to [http://<Service_URL>]

TRACE [org.springframework.ws.server.MessageTracing.received] - Received request [<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:DelRequest xmlns:ns2="http://<changed_address>"><ns2:userId>ncc1@%</ns2:userId><ns2:dateFromMillis>1309042800000</ns2:dateFromMillis><ns2:dateToMillis>1311721200000</ns2:dateToMillis></ns2:DelRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>]

DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping] - Looking up endpoint for [{<changed_address>}DelRequest]

DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher] - Endpoint mapping [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping@6ee035] maps request to endpoint [public final net.org.messagehistory.schema.GetDelResponse net.org.messagehistory.service.endpoint.MessageHistoryEndpoint.delHistory(net.org.messagehistory.schema.GetListRequest) throws javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException]

DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.soap.server.SoapMessageDispatcher] - Testing endpoint adapter [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter@1a23f67]

DEBUG [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter] - Unmarshalled payload request to [net.org.messagehistory.schema.DelRequest@c76003]
```

The end error message is now 'Argument type Mismatch' which I found was generated from one of the methods from within WebServiceTemplate.class

Can somebody suggest what coudl be the problem here?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766328/spring-ws-unavailable-upon-requesting-connection)?

Comment: I closed that question down by posting what I thought was the appropriate answer at the time as it seemed to have worked. But I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this sorted. So, just wanted to share the solution that somebody might find helpful.

Make sure that the Endpoint method is annotated with the following 
@PayloadRoot(localPart = MESSAGES_TO_DELETE, namespace = MESSAGE_NAMESPACE) 
where localpart is the same as the your payload request in the schema.xsd

Thanks